# ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class on forEach call

Tags: java, foreach, classcastexception

I'm trying to make a list of Integers from an attribute of an object inside a list, but I keep getting this error, I've tried using lambdas, and common loops, but I can't figure out what's the problem here.

```
private LinkedHashMap<String, ExportHeaderDTO> generateColumns(final ExportRequestDTO exportRequestDTO) {
    final LinkedHashMap<String, ExportHeaderDTO> headerMap;
    log.info("Generating xls columns...");
    List<AttributeForExport> attributes;
     [...]
        List<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<>();
        exportRequestDTO.getAttributeDTOListToInclude().forEach(attributeDTO -> ids.add(attributeDTO.getId()));
        log.info("Getting attributes with ids: {}", ids.toString());
        attributes = this.getAttributesToExport(ids);
    }
```

This is the object:

```
    public class AttributeDTO implements Serializable {
    private Integer id;
    private Integer taxonomyCode;
    private Integer dataTypeId;
    private String description;
    private String maxInstance;
    private List<String> paths;
    }
```

EDIT:

Here is the stacktrace I can show, the line giving the error is the one with the forEach call.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class org.easa.eccairs.occurrences.dtos.AttributeDTO (java.util.LinkedHashMap is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; org.easa.eccairs.occurrences.dtos.AttributeDTO is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
at org.easa.eccairs.export.service.impl.ExcelExportServiceImpl.generateColumns(ExcelExportServiceImpl.java:776)
at org.easa.eccairs.export.service.impl.ExcelExportServiceImpl.getDataAndProcessXlsFile(ExcelExportServiceImpl.java:620)
at org.easa.eccairs.export.service.impl.ExcelExportServiceImpl.exportToXlsAsync(ExcelExportServiceImpl.java:573)
at org.easa.eccairs.export.service.impl.ExportServiceImpl.lambda$exportXls$2(ExportServiceImpl.java:143)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncRun.run(CompletableFuture.java:1736)
at org.springframework.security.concurrent.DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable.run(DelegatingSecurityContextRunnable.java:84)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Comment: The problem is related to a `LinkedHashMap`. Can you provide the entire stacktrace and show which line is causing this error?

Comment: Can you share some more code as this code is not showing any relation between linkedhashmap & foreach call you are having

Comment: "I keep getting this error", which one? Please include the execption / stack trace

Comment: What is the return type of `getAttributeDTOListToInclude()`?

Comment: @Japhei edited and added the stacktrace

Comment: @jhueg read the title please

Comment: @M.Prokhorov  List<AttributeForExport>

Comment: @AlejandroPachecoTejeda, well, according to your exception, the actual runtime type of that list is `List<LinkedHashMap<?, ?>>`. Find whatever code fills that list, and fix it, so the list actually contains the data you say it does.

Comment: @AlejandroPachecoTejeda where is this line: `ExcelExportServiceImpl.java:776`? Is it the `forEach` loop after your `ids` list?  If so it seelms like the return type of `getAttributeDTOListToInclude()` is `List<LinkedHashMap<?, ?>>` instead of `List<AttributeDTO>`. Can you provide this method? And what class is `AttributeForExport`?

Comment: @Japhei Yes, it's the forEach's line. This is the method, just a getter from another Object containing the List:
 `public List<AttributeDTO> getAttributeDTOListToInclude() {
        return this.attributeDTOListToInclude;
    }`
and this is the attribute itself, nothing complex here apparently:
    `private List<AttributeDTO> attributeDTOListToInclude;`

Don't know why it's returning `List<LinkedHashMap<?, ?>>`

Comment: @AlejandroPachecoTejeda That's weird. Can you save the returned value in a local vairable `List<AttributeDTO>` and then iterate through it with a for (not forEach) loop for debugging purposes? According to the error message the error should accure when creating the local variable. But still there shouldn't be any need to cast?!?

Comment: This is probably caused by code which is not currently shown in your question, which is performing an unchecked cast.  Enable all compiler warnings, and pay attention to them.